# component in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, uicomponent, ui-form, ui

How to pass dynamic value for  `<item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>` this component.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="order_comment">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>                      
                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Comment</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

I also refer http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_modifier_concept.html.   But this only for admin form.

How to do this...Is there any possibility.....

Comment: You need to disable component?

Comment: yes...@Suresh Chikani

Comment: Based on above way, Its perfect way to disable component, Have you faced any issue related to above XML?

Comment: the component is disable correctly.But i want to disable/enable this component dynamically from admin side- Enable Order_Comment Yes/no configuration

Comment: @PriyaM Show your entire listing.xml file?

Comment: I have added Order Comment column in sales order grid. so my entire listing file was above mentioned.

Comment: Had you tried with below answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **Class** as your classpath in column tag,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="order_comment" class="Mymodule\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Comment">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Comment</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Create file at location,
You need to pass your conditions

**Under prepare() function**

Create Commment.php
**Mymodule\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Comment.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Mymodule\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;


class Comment extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }


    /**
     * Prepare component configuration
     * @return void
     */
    public function prepare()
    {
        parent::prepare();
        /* pass your conditions here in if  */
        if (YOUR_CONDITIONS) { 
            $this->_data['config']['componentDisabled'] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if ($this->storeManager->isSingleStoreMode()) you need to pass your conditions here

Comment: You have to keep your conditions instead of $this->storeManager->isSingleStoreMode() in if statement

Comment: Try with this, public function prepare() { parent::prepare(); /* pass your conditions here in if */ $helper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Xxx\OrderComment\Helper\Data'); if (!$helper->isEnable()) {  $this->_data['config']['componentDisabled'] = true; }}

Comment: still showing....

Comment: try to check by print object using $this->_data['config'] any value is getting or not.

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh ...Its working charm.Thanks for spend  ur time with my questions

Comment: Welcome, Glad to help you.Whats the issue actually was?